# Left join with additional variable check

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (t1, t2, t3) with different data. I need to add a new table (t4) and add to it a new column for all rows in the first 3 tables. To add new records I need to loop through the each table and LEFT JOIN t4 to make sure the records do not exists already. The only way to associate new records in t4 with other tables is to use 2 columns from each: table name and row id. The problem that I have is that row IDs in those tables are numeric and auto-incremented, i.e. not unique.

My t4 structure is like this:

```
id   |  tbl (t1, t2 or t3)  |  row_id (from t1-t3)  | new_val
```

and I'm trying to select from t1-t3 only the values not present in t4

```
SELECT 
   `".$c1."` AS id,          
   `".$c2."` AS item
FROM ".$tb."
LEFT JOIN t4 ON (".$tb.".`".$c1."` = t4.row_id) 
WHERE t4.tbl = ".$tb."
```

So if I were to loop through **t1** and store my data in **t4** the results would look like:

```
Table t4

----------------------------
id |  tbl | row_id | new_val 
----------------------------
1  |  t1  |   1    | val1
----------------------------
2  |  t1  |   2    | val2
----------------------------
3  |  t1  |   3    | val3
```

However, if I were to loop through **t2** next it will have to skip rows 1-3, assuming they are already stored, because both have the same row IDs. To avoid this I need to use both row ID and table name but I'm not sure how to integrate this in one query.

The desired outcome should look like:

```
Table t4

----------------------------
id |  tbl | row_id | new_val 
----------------------------
1  |  t1  |   1    | val1
----------------------------
2  |  t1  |   2    | val2
----------------------------
3  |  t1  |   3    | val3
----------------------------
4  |  t2  |   1    | blah
----------------------------
5  |  t2  |   2    | blah2
----------------------------
6  |  t2  |   3    | blah3
----------------------------
7  |  t3  |   1    | zzz1
----------------------------
8  |  t3  |   2    | zzz2
----------------------------
9  |  t3  |   3    | zzz3
```

Comment: If t4 is new, why would there be any data in it

Comment: I will generate data and store in t4 if I don't find it in t4.

Comment: No, not exacly. There are no duplicates in t1- t3 except row IDs. That's why I need to use both row ID and table name.

Comment: Basically I think you need to do a quick Basic Relational Database design course/tutorial. The design you show sounds ridiculously complicated and I am not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you have a practical solution as well?

Comment: If you can tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, I will have a try

Answer (score 0):

If I have corectly understood your question, your query should be similar to this:

```
SELECT 
   `".$c1."` AS id,          
   `".$c2."` AS item
FROM ".$tb."
LEFT JOIN t4 ON (".$tb.".`".$c1."` = t4.row_id) 
WHERE t4.row_id = NULL
      AND t4.tbl = ".$tb."
```

In the WHERE condition you have to select only the ones where `t4.row_id` is `NULL` because it means that the row is present in `".$tb."` but not in `t4`.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but the problem is all 3 tables t1 - t3 can have the same row numbers, so ".$tb.".`".$c1."` = t4.row_id is not sufficient, unless I also indicate which table it is associated with.

Comment: I edited the query in order to include the extra condition. I think that now it should return the result you expect.
Please let us know. It seems a recurring problem when tables in production need to be updated :)